# Drawback of using Arrays.sort() method in Java instead of QuickSort or MergeSort

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I was just doing an array problem and the solution there uses quicksort but I instead used Arrays.sort() method.Now I think Arrays.sort() uses quicksort with primitive types and mergesort for object types.
So is there any drawback in using the

> Arrays.sort()

method directly in java instead of doing a whole implementation for Quick or merge sort.Or if both are same why to do a lengthy implementation instead of using the Arrays.sort() method?

Comment: When in doubt: measure yourself; with the data sets that your application will be dealing with. Beyond that: normally,re-use of existing technology should be preferred over re-inventing the wheel. Keep in mind: each line of code that you write ... you have to carry on, and maintain in the future.

Comment: So you are suggesting Arrays.sort() over Quicksort right?

Comment: Always go for what most people use first. `Arrays.sort()` has an infinitely higher likelihood to work as intended than your own implementation of whatever (sorting) algorithm you implement yourself due to the amount of expertise, testing, and verification (by those many users) that went into it. Unless your requirements are so specific that a stock implementation won't cut it.

Comment: The only reason to implement quick/merge sort yourself is for you to learn how they work and where the pitfalls are. It teaches you how to program. But in real life, it's better to use existing code, keeping in mind that (a) you don't overly burden your dependencies just to do something simple, and (b) not everything written by someone on the Internet is good code. The standard Java API does not suffer from these issues. Use it as much as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you really need (proven by measurements) a more efficient implementation, *and* can come up with one, it always makes much more sense to use `Arrays.sort`. It is efficient and well-tested. It rarely makes any sense at all to implement Quicksort or Merge Sort, as these are generic sorting algorithms. It might make sense to implement a custom sorting algorithm that uses some properties of your data that Java has no way of using (counting sort and bucket sort are nice examples).

As for `Arrays.sort`, Oracle implementation works as follows:

1. For `int`, `long`, `float` and `double` there are essentially three algorithms: Insertion Sort, Dual-Pivot Stable Quicksort and Merge Sort.

1.1. If the array is large enough (currently larger than 286 elements) *and* it's not “almost sorted” (determined dynamically), *then* Merge Sort is used.

1.2. Otherwise, if the array is very small (currently less than 47 elements), then Insertion Sort is used.

1.3. Otherwise (if the array is not that small, but either smaller than 286 elements or mostly sorted), Dual-Pivot Quicksort is used.

2. For `short` and `char`, there are Insertion Sort, Dual-Pivot Stable Quicksort and Counting Sort.

2.1. If the array is larger than a certain threshold (currently 3200 elements), then Counting Sort is used.

2.2. Otherwise, similarly to larger types, Insertion Sort or Dual-Pivot Stable Quicksort is used (using the threshold of 47 elements).

3. For bytes, it's like for shorts, but Counting Sort is used when there are more than 29 elements (since it doesn't require that much memory).
4. For reference types, things are complicated.

4.1. If the `java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort` property is set, then some sort of legacy Merge Sort is used (surprisingly), which falls back to Insertion Sort on really small arrays (less than 7 elements).

4.2. Otherwise, TimSort is used ([Tim Pieter's list sort for Python](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt)), which is something similar to Merge Sort, but for arrays of less than 32 objects no merging is performed.

The point of the above is that Java people really did their research instead of blindly implementing a random sorting algorithm, hoping that everyone will be happy with it.

In my experience, I find `Arrays.sort` to be extremely efficient. I can think of two reasons to implement a custom algorithm: the aforementioned case using certain data properties, and sorting data that comes in different “parallel” arrays that we can't merge into one array of composite objects for whatever reason (performance, or perhaps we just don't have control over the code that produced those arrays).

Comment: @Sergey..Thanks very much..it was loads of good information..:)